# For in loop and if statement in Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I'm Trying to figure out how this works.
Example One:

```
n = ["1ab", "2an", "3bca", "4adc"]
l = ["1", "2", "3"]
for m in n:
    if "a" in m:
        for k in l:
            if k in m:
                print k
1
2
3
```

Now I will try to print last member of n list.

```
n = ["1ab", "2an", "3bca", "4adc"]
l = ["1", "2", "3"]
for m in n:
    if "a" in m:
        for k in l:
            if not k in m:
                print k

2
3
1
3
1
2
1
2
3
```

I need to print a list member which does not contain any number listed in l variable but contains "a" in it.

Comment: Please explain a bit more what you are trying to do

Comment: I need to print a list member which does not contain any number listed in l variable but contains "a" in it.

Comment: Then you should edit your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = ["1ab", "2an", "3bca", "4adc"]
l = ["1", "2", "3"]
for m in n:
    if "a" in m:
        if not any([k in m for k in l]):
            print m

4adc
```

Answer (score 7):

Since 4 is not in your list `l` , you cannot print it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So how to print it?

Comment: @iRex it helps a bit more if you say what your are trying to achieve?

Comment: @ Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy I need to compare if variable n contains any number of indicated in the variable l. Then Print them separately. In second example I need to print ""4adc".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your second to last line. For every loop through n you loop through l and there are three members of n that meet if not k in m: condition. So

Loop 1 prints: 2,3
Loop 2 prints: 1,3
Loop 3 prints: 1,2
Loop 4 prints: 1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l   
['1', '2', '3']
>>> n   
['1ab', '2an', '3bca', '4adc']
for el in n: 
    if(el[0] not in l):
        print(el)

4adc
```

Or if you just want to print 4, based on your list sequence:

```
for el in n: 
    if(el[0] not in l):
        print(el[0])
```

Now you just added to your question, "but contains "a"", add second iff.

```
    for el in n: 
        if(el[0] not in l):
            if('a' in el):
                print(el[0],el)
```